# Emacs can't reset Ctrl-d key behaviour

Tags: emacs

I wanted to change the behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> key. So it will delete a word backward. I created a function:

```
(defun backward-delete-word (arg)
      "Delete characters backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
      (interactive "p")
      (delete-region (point) (progn (backward-word arg) (point))))
```

Then inserted this into `emacs.d`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-d") 'backward-delete-word)
```

It works in fundamental-mode, but in php-mode it just removes the next character. When I click

> Ctrl-h k Ctrl-d

Emacs gives this:

```
C-d runs the command c-electric-delete-forward, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in `cc-cmds.el'.

It is bound to C-d.

(c-electric-delete-forward ARG)
```

Somehow, it was reset to another function. How to find out, where it was reset and make it work with my function instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have `php-mode` so I can't say for sure, but the binding is likely overriden in `php-mode-map` (which, as a major mode map, has higher precedence than the global map).

You can check by using <kbd>C-h b</kbd> to list all available key bindings and look for `C-d` or `c-electric-delete-forward` in the output buffer to see in which keymap the binding is defined.

Assuming `php-mode-map` overrides the <kbd>C-d</kbd> binding, you can disable it using

```lisp
(define-key php-mode-map (kbd "C-d") nil)
```