# Redefine M-z from zap-to-char

Tags: emacs

Clicking <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Alt-z</kbd> gives this:

> M-z runs the command zap-to-char, which is an interactive compiled
>   Lisp function in `simple.el'.
>
> It is bound to M-z.
>
> (zap-to-char ARG CHAR)
>
> Kill up to and including ARGth occurrence of CHAR. Case is ignored if
>   `case-fold-search' is non-nil in the current buffer. Goes backward if
>   ARG is negative; error if CHAR not found.

---

I never use this function, but the keys are located in a very good position. So I wanted to redefine this sequence. But I couldn't. Even when I execute this command in .emacs:

`(global-set-key (kbd "\M-z") 'backward-delete-word)` M-z is still bound to `zap-to-char`.

Approach, suggested here, didn't help:

[Emacs can't reset Ctrl-d key behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703760/emacs-cant-reset-ctrl-d-key-behaviour)

Comment: Don't forget to reload the .emacs file, `M-x load-file ~/.emacs`.

Comment: @Patrick I used C-x C-e to compile the expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a `\` in 'kbd'. Also, I think you're looking for `backward-kill-word`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-z") 'backward-kill-word)
```

EDIT: I didn't notice that the page you linked to defines `backward-delete-word`. If you have that function defined, you can use it instead of `backward-kill-word` here.